# Show only 6th digit of reaction time

Tags: python

I am running a reaction time experiment. I am very new to python and I'm using a package called psychopy (though I guess this is a python question). I have a reaction time and **I just want to consistently display ONLY the 6th digit after the decimal (microsecond)**.

This code shows the RT to 6 digits:

`msg="Correct! RT=%.6f" %(resp.rt)` produces this on the display: 0.427716

But I want to display only the last digit, in this example 6.

I have used this code successfully:

```
msg= str(resp.rt)[-7]
```

But, the corresponding digits displayed are sometimes the 5th and sometimes the 6th. Instead of always the 6th. I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tests = [
    0.4277169,    
    0.427716,
    0.42771,
    999.42771,
    999.427716    
    ]

for rt in tests:
    print('Correct! RT = %d' % (rt*10**6 % 10, ))
```

yields

```
Correct! RT = 6    # This shows the correct digit if rt has more than 6 significant digits
Correct! RT = 6
Correct! RT = 0    # This shows a zero is used if rt has < 6 significant digits
Correct! RT = 0
Correct! RT = 6
```

Comment: This has consistently given me 6 digits in my testing (about 100 digits generated). So I think this has done it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can index into the string directly:

```
>>> val = 0.427716
>>> print str(val)[7]
6
```

...but that can lead to surprises with missing digits:

```
>>> val = 0.5
>>> str(val)[7]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

...so you're best off formatting the string output to a specified number of digits and then indexing into that:

```
>>> def GetSixthDigit(f):
...    s = "%2.6f" % f
...    return s[7]
... 
>>> GetSixthDigit(0.427716)
'6'
>>> GetSixthDigit(0.5)
'0'
```